# An alternative for cancel.

Tags: meaning

what is the best alternative for the word "cancel" to be used in a phrase like "to cancel a contract".can I use disrupt or maybe abolish??? what is the standard word that is used in official language?

Comment: What "official language" do you mean? English has none.

Comment: I think 'cancel' is OK, even though other words would work here. Why do you think it needs to be changed?

Comment: I don't know why Mitch, maybe lack of English knowledge or maybe I want it to look more complicated like other official papers.

Comment: There is "abrogate" perhaps that is what you want.

Comment: @Eilia In that case there is no contract: the union declined to enter into the contract proposal.

Comment: @ToughGuy wel, that's the point, that if you want technical legal language, I think 'cancel' is the best to mean exactly that, and another technical term would mean something slightly different. If this is not legal and you just want to sound fancy, use some of the suggests given. But beware, your 'fancy' might be taken wrongly as someone else's technical term, and then you might have a legal battle, depending on the context.

Comment: If you're not just curious but trying to write an actual contract, you shouldn't be here; you should be talking to a lawyer. We do not hold ourselves out as experts on law, and in fact it would for many of us be illegal to do so.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cancel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cancel* is the usual term. Here's an example from the standard NAEGA 2 FOB contract:

> In case of prohibition of export, blockade or hostilities or in case of any executive or legislative act done by or on behalf of the country of origin or of the territory where the ports of shipment named herein are situate, restricting export, whether partially or otherwise, any such restriction shall be deemed by both parties to apply to this contract and to the extent of such total or partial restriction to prevent fulfillment and to that extent this contract or any unfulfilled portion thereof shall be **cancelled** without prejudice to seller’s entitlement to carrying charges. Seller shall advise buyer without delay of the reasons therefor, and if required by buyer, seller shall provide certification of the North American Export Grain Association, Inc., as sufficient evidence for **cancellation** under this clause.

If you want to get really fancy you can use *abrogate*, but that is usually reserved for instances when a higher authority such as a court terminates the operation of the contract.

Comment: what about canceling a deal?? do we have a special word for that?

Comment: @ToughGuy Colloquially we speak of "calling off" a deal or "pulling out" of a deal; but a "deal" is a contract, and if you want a neutral term acceptable in all registers, *cancel* is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can "**void**" a contract, which in this sense is defined by Merriam-Webster as "nullify, annul".  Usually, however, this usage means not that the parties agreed to cancel the contract, but that one party acted in a manner expressly forbidden by the contract ("breach of contract"), or that the contract itself is invalid, most often because one or more of its provisions turns out to be illegal.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Terminate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/terminate?q=Terminate)** - bring to an end

As in, "We are going to **terminate** your contract."

Comment: "Termination" does not cancel a contract; it declares the contract, under the terms of the contract itself, to be complete.